# Progress bar in table

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created a table that will echo out data. This table has a progress section which shows the percentage of the work completed based on data collected from the database.

The issue that I have is the progress bar. The bar itself does not work for every row of the table. It seems to only show the percentage for the first row.

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFEd4.jpg)

Here is my code:

```js
// on page load...
moveProgressBar();
// on browser resize...
$(window).resize(function() {
  moveProgressBar();
});

// SIGNATURE PROGRESS
function moveProgressBar() {
  console.log("moveProgressBar");
  var getPercent = ($('.progress-wrap').data('progress-percent') / 100);
  var getProgressWrapWidth = $('.progress-wrap').width();
  var progressTotal = getPercent * getProgressWrapWidth;
  var animationLength = 2500;

  // on page load, animate percentage bar to data percentage length
  // .stop() used to prevent animation queueing
  $('.progress-bar').stop().animate({
    left: progressTotal
  }, animationLength);
}
```

```html
<!-- progress bar & progress count -->

<div id="block_container">
  <div class="percentext">
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($pra['completed_sessions']);?> /
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($pra['number_of_sessions']);?>
  </div>
  <div class="progressblock">
    <div class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="<?php print ((($pra['completed_sessions'])/($pra['number_of_sessions']))*100);?>">
      <div class="progress-bar progress">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- END OF progress bar & progress count -->
```

Comment: The code snippet is not working, and It is unclear what behavior do you expect. How do you get the percent number while the page is loading ? and if $('.progress-bar') refers to several bars why only one variable progressTotal ?

Comment: because you need to work with each one separately.... There is no bulk operation here. `progressTotal` is going to be the first element

Comment: @epascarello would you be able to provide an example of what that would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the widths to each one individually. You are selecting all of them and setting the width to the value of the first one.

```js
// select all the elements that are progress bar
$("[data-progress-percent]")
  // loop over the jQuery collection
  .each( function () {
    // get the current one in the iteration
    var wrapper = $(this);
    // get the values
    var width = wrapper.width();
    var percentage = wrapper.data("progress-percent");
    // determine the width of the bar
    var barWidth = width * percentage/100;
    // find the element to animate inside the current wrapper
    wrapper
     .find(".progress-bar")
       .stop()
       .animate({width: barWidth + "px"}, 1000);
  });
```

```css
.progress-wrap {
  width: 80%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 1em;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 20px;
  width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="45">
  <div class="progress-bar progress">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="15">
  <div class="progress-bar progress">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="95">
  <div class="progress-bar progress">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<script>
    completed = /*get completed*/;
    total = /*get total*/;
    percentage = completed / total;
    bar = document.getElementById('progress-bar progress'); //Use id and not class
    bar.style.width = percentage+"%";
</script>
```